# How do I install mysql 5.1 for my set up? (ideally using brew)

Tags: mysql, installation, environment

I need to install MySQL 5.1 for my rails application. Using Homebrew, I am unable to install a specific version. I tried brew install mysql51, but that didn't work.

Installing the right version from the mysql site did not work properly for me. I want to be able to start the server easily from the command line using something like mysql.server start.

When I installed 5.1 from the official site, I got this rails error:

dlopen(/Users/sb1752/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sb1752/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/sb1752/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

I don't get this error if I do a brew install though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [corresponding installer from the official site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html) and install.

Comment: Sure. But this didn't end up working for me properly. How do I get this to work so that I can do mysql.server start from the command line to get the server to start properly. Brew installs it differently and it ends up working properly with my rails environment.

Comment: I did install it this way and it works properly for me. I start it through a Preferences pane, though.

Comment: I tried starting through the preference pane, but it didn't work. It remains "stopped"